# Select2 not being applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use [Select2](https://select2.org) to replace a multi-select drop down on my site.

The plan is that a user can select a list of countries by typing the country, which will then be auto-completed and stored in a tag-like structure, similar to how StackOverflow tags work.

For some reason, nothing is happening when I call the select2 function in my code.

Below I've included my code and a link to a JSFiddle.

**Head:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Countries to choose from

    var countries = [{
        id: 1,
        text: 'United Kingdom'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        text: 'United States of America'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        text: 'Germany'
    }, ];

    // Create countries dropdown
    $('#allowedCountries').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select allowed countries',
        data: countries,
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
    });
})
```

**JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/3ms60wkw/

Comment: In your jsfiddle the scripts are loaded in incorrect order. jquery should be the first .js to load

Comment: @PauloRamos https://jsfiddle.net/dzutg2ed/1/ working. hmm, I have the files in the order shown in the code above, I'm wondering if there is any other script being pulled in before the head that is affecting this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just call

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

before

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

and it should work perfectly fine

Comment: I have the scripts in the order shown in my post, but I've tested now with correct order in the JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/dzutg2ed/1/) and seems to be working. I think the problem may be hidden in an included file.

Comment: Yep, this was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Jquery should be loaded first because select 2 depends on top of JQuery